# Bootstrap-datepicker: seemingly unpredictable behaviour

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) and I have a strange behaviour. Sometimes it loads correctly, sometimes not:

[image: Failed datepicker load]

When it loads correctly this element is appended to `body` element when opening button is clicked (generated html):

```
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" style="top: 376px; left: 218.656px; z-index: 10; display: block;">
  <div class="datepicker-days" style="">
    <table class="table-condensed">
      <!-- [...] -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other times (most of times) this element is yet present in `body` as last body's child-node (generated html, no inner html in #ui-datepicker-div):

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
</div>
```

and also this element is yet present right after the opening button. i.e. this is appended to `<div id="startdate-container">` element (datepicker form element) as its last child-node (generated html):

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
  <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <!-- [...] -->
  </div>
  <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <!-- [...] -->
  </table>
</div>
```

Context details: I'm using it in an angularjs (1.6.x) directive, with requirejs.

requirejs configuration:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    bootstrapDatepicker: 'bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: { exports: 'jquery' },
    bootstrapDatepicker: ['jquery']
  }
})
```

datepicker loading:

```
define([
  'angular',
  'bootstrapDatepicker',
  'bootstrap',
  'css!bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css'
], function (angular) {
  angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('taskCreator', [function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      require: '^parentController',
      templateUrl: 'templates/template.html',
      link: function link(scope, el, attrs, controller) {

        $('#startdate-container').datepicker({
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
          weekStart: 1,
          maxViewMode: 3,
          todayBtn: "linked",
          multidate: false,
          daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
})
```

And directive's template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start:</label>
  <div id="startDate" class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="startdate-container" class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved. Post here for others.

Since modules loading order is not guaranteed, the problem occurs when jquery-ui module (if you use it in your project) is loaded after bootstrap-datepicker module: it overrides `$.fn.datepicker`

Although bootstrap-datepicker doesn't depends on jquery-ui you can solve the issue editing your requirejs config, forcing it to load previously than bootstrap-datepicker:

requirejs configuration to solve:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    jqueryui: 'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
    bootstrapDatepicker: 'bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: { exports: 'jquery' },
    jqueryui: ['jquery'],
    bootstrapDatepicker: ['jquery', 'jqueryui']
  }
})
```